# ROOT(CERN) calling method creates segfault even without trying the first line (seems like it's SetBranchAddress)

Tags: c++11, root-framework

I try to read root file as usual using `SetBranchAddress` method, but when i run `getHist()` method it gives me segfault and even doesn't print "called getHist".

I use ROOT 6.10 and compile my code with gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu2) 4.8.5 using `make`.

```
#define nSec 110

using namespace std;

void getHist(TString filename, TH1D* h1Hnum)
{
  cout << "called getHist" << endl;

  // TChain *theChain1 = new TChain("T");

  TFile *file = new TFile(filename);
  TTree *theChain1 = (TTree*)file->Get("T");
  if (!theChain1) { std::cout << "Error: tree not found." << std::endl; delete file; return; }

  cout << filename << endl;
  // theChain1->Add(filename);

  Int_t EventID1;
  Int_t nPart1;
  Int_t nColl1;
  Int_t TrackID1[100000];
  Int_t ParentID1[100000];
  Int_t StationID1[100000];
  Double_t X1[100000];
  Double_t Y1[100000];
  Double_t Z1[100000];
  Double_t Momentum1[100000];
  Double_t Px1[100000];
  Double_t Py1[100000];
  Double_t Pz1[100000];
  Double_t Time1[100000];
  Double_t PdgID1[100000];

  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("EventID", &EventID1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("nPart", &nPart1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("nColl", &nColl1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("TrackID", TrackID1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("ParentID", ParentID1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("StationID", StationID1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("X", X1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Y", Y1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Z", Z1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Momentum", Momentum1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Px", Px1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Py", Py1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Pz", Pz1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("Time", Time1);
  theChain1->SetBranchAddress("PdgID", PdgID1);

  Long_t nEv1 = theChain1->GetEntries();

  ////////// Loop 1 //////////
  for (Long_t j = 0; j <  nEv1; ++j) {
    theChain1->GetEntry(j);
    // h1nColl->Fill(nColl1);

    Int_t nPhot[nSec] = {0};
    Bool_t isChecked[nSec] = {false};

    for (Int_t i = 0; i < nPart1; ++i){
      if (StationID1[i] < 0) continue;
      if (isChecked[StationID1[i]]) continue;

      nPhot[StationID1[i]] ++;
      if (nPhot[StationID1[i]] > 20.){
        // h1Hnum->Fill(StationID[i]);
        isChecked[StationID1[i]] = true;
      }
    }

    Int_t numOfHits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSec; ++i)
      if (isChecked[i]) numOfHits++;

    h1Hnum->Fill(numOfHits);
  }

  cout << "returning hist" << endl;

}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  #define NHIST 10

  TH1D *array[NHIST];

  cout << "start looping" << endl;

  // printHello();
  // getHist(filename);


  for (Int_t i = 0; i < NHIST; ++i) {
    TString filename = "newData_";
    filename += TString (std::to_string(i+1));
    filename += TString(".root");

    array[i] = new TH1D(TString("Hit Number"+std::to_string(i)),TString("HitNumber"+std::to_string(i)), nSec, -0.5, nSec-0.5);


    cout << "trying to get hist "<< filename << endl;

    getHist(filename, array[i]);

    cout << "trying to make new hist "  << endl;

    cout << "trying to set color" << endl;
    array[i]->SetLineColor(i);
    // delete htemp;
  }

  cout << "finish looping" << endl;

  TApplication *app = new TApplication("name", &argc, argv);
  cout << "TApp created" << endl;

  TCanvas *c = new TCanvas();

  array[0]->Draw();
  for (Int_t i = 1; i < NHIST; ++i) {
    array[i]->Draw("SAME");
  }
  // c->Show();
  // app->Run();
  std::cin;

  delete[] array;
  delete c;

  return 0;
}
```

It prints:
start looping

```
trying to get hist newData_1.root
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

But if i comment all lines with `SetBranchAdress` that works and method `getHist` is called in loop.
(actual output is to long but believe me, there's all thing that are printed by cout)

Comment: Please change the `root` tag to `root-framework`. The former is for unix-like systems admin accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it just changing array definition to dynamic.
Before:

```
Int_t TrackID1[100000];
```

After:

```
Int_t *TrackID1 = new Int_t[100000];
```